# Add footer to ListView if ArrayList size isn't 0

Tags: java, android

I only want my footer view to load if the size of my array is greater than 0. If I test it with an if statement, the footer doesn't load at all, even though the size of the array is greater than 0.

Here's the code to setup the footer:

```
private void setupFooterView()
{
    footerView = (LoadMoreListItem) getSherlockActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.load_more, null);
    footerView.showFooterText(); 
    mListView.addFooterView(footerView);     
}
```

The onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.network_listview, container, false);
    mListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.network_listview);     

    aToken = getSherlockActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("token");
    aTokenSecret = getSherlockActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("token_secret");
    context = getSherlockActivity().getBaseContext();       

    if (timeline_arg.size != 0) { 
       setupFooterView(); // doesnt load if timeline_arg (ArrayList) is not 0 
    } 

    // nothing special, just sets up baseadapter and passes arraylist
    attachAdapter();
}
```

Why doesn't this work? It seemed so obvious, but ended up being more complicated than I thought.

Comment: Are you positive that timeline_arg is not actually 0? onCreateView is called before any other onCreate activity happens so if you're setting its contents later it will be empty at this point.

Comment: @Rarw you're correct, it was 0 :) i remembered now that i set the array in attachAdapter. The source file is extremely long so i guess i overlooked it :p